# Bootstrap Navbar não está funcional

Tags: css, bootstrap

Eu já copiei conforme a documentação do Bootstrap porém meu navbar não está funcionando corretamente quando eu diminuo a tela. O botão aparece normal, porém quando quando eu clicar, ele deveria abrir um menu com as opções do meu "nav-content" porém nada acontece quando clico no botão. Revisei várias vezes, será que não importei algo?

[image: Tela Cheia]

[image: Tela Diminuida]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">

    <!-- CSS Personalizada -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">

    <!-- Ícone da Página na aba -->
    <link rel="icon" href="imagens/bonfireicon.png">

    <title>Weeeelcome!</title>

</head>
<body>

    <!-- Navigation Bar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-faded">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company</a>
        <!-- Hide Button -->
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-content"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toogle Navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <!-- NavBar Content -->
        <div class=" collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-content">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Serviços</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!--Search Box -->
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my my-lg-0">
                <input type="text" class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="Digite sua pesquisa aqui..." aria-label="Search">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">Pesquisar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>


    <div class="container">

        <div class="starter-template">
            <h1 class="">What up!</h1>
            <p class="lead">Bonfire lit.</p>
        </div>

    </div>


    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O que seria não funcionar corretamente? O que você precisa que o NAV faça ?

Comment: Eu preciso que quando eu redimencionar ela para um tamanho pequeno, o conteúdo dos "nav-item" sejam agrupados no botão que criei, de forma que em um celular, consiga manter uma boa visualização. Porém quando clico no botão (segunda imagem) nada acontece. E segundo a documentação do Bootstrap já deveria funcionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro o Jquery, para depois usar o bootstrap.

Se você observar o console do desenvolvedor, irá perceber o erro:

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Então troque:

```
<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Por:

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: Isso que você disse esta correto para as APIs de interação jQuery e elementos DOM para Bootstrap, mas para a responsividade não deve ser o problema, já que é possivel usar bootstrap.css sem jQuery.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento faz um pouco de sentido, no entanto eu nem baixei seu código para fazer o teste, percebi esse problema (que já passei por ele), o menu (navbar) estava de boa, mas quando ele ficava responsivo (pequeno) em um dispositivo menor, ele não funcionava, então pesquisei dias, até ver que o problema era esse.. kkkk A pergunta que não quer calar, funcionou seu código aí? (Se não funcionou, disponibiliza seu projeto para termos acesso a todos os arquivos css e js que vocês etá usando), aí poderei te ajudar mais :)

Comment: Caaaaaaaara! Muito obrigado! Eu não sabia que deveria colocar o Jquery antes do Javascript. Funcionou depois que troquei como indicou. Muitíssimo obrigado. 
:D